# java os-x watchservice deadlocks

Tags: java, macos, deadlock, watchservice

I'm wondering if others have seen the Java 8 Watch Service on the OS X hang (deadlock).

I'm using the Watch service (obtained using FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService()) for monitoring CREATE/DELETE/MODIFY events associated with files/sub-directories under a directory. The service appears to work fine on Windows, but on OS X appears to hang when several new directories are created in a short time span. I haven't had the time to precisely characterize the conditions that cause this, but rapid directory creation and renaming of those directories under the folder being watched easily reproduces the problem.

To be precise, the thread in our code that invokes the Path.register() function (for registering a directory with the watch service) appears to hang with the following stack trace:

```
at sun.nio.fs.PollingWatchService$PollingWatchKey.disable(PollingWatchService.java:296)
at sun.nio.fs.PollingWatchService.doPrivilegedRegister(PollingWatchService.java:169)
at sun.nio.fs.PollingWatchService.access$000(PollingWatchService.java:45)
at sun.nio.fs.PollingWatchService$2.run(PollingWatchService.java:128)
at sun.nio.fs.PollingWatchService$2.run(PollingWatchService.java:125)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.nio.fs.PollingWatchService.register(PollingWatchService.java:124)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.register(UnixPath.java:897)
at myClass.functionFoo (myClass:xyz)    <----- I invoke register() here.
```

Looks like bug# JDK-8079620 logged a few months ago on the OpenJDK site has a similar set of symptoms.

Any one else encountered this problem? Any suggested workarounds?

Comment: I encountered this about 8 months ago and reported it to Oracle (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8079620). Unfortunately there was no response up until now. I guess for now we have to get through the way it is.